# Ubuntu 16.04 Network Manager DHCP and PXE setup. Can't find `dnsmasq.conf`

Tags: networking, dhcp, pxe

I'm about to upgrade my (seperate computer) firewall (Going from IPCop to IPFire). I'd like to use PXE to boot the upgrade on the firewall.

I depend on the firewall system for DHCP, so when it's down for reinstallation, nobody will get an IP address.

I think I know the magic to add to `dnsmasq.conf` to cause it to serve DHCP, but, I don't see `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`. Using `locate` says:

```
$ locate dnsmasq.conf
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/dnsmasq.conf
/snap/core/5548/etc/dbus-1/system.d/dnsmasq.conf
/snap/core/5662/etc/dbus-1/system.d/dnsmasq.conf
/snap/core/5742/etc/dbus-1/system.d/dnsmasq.conf
/usr/share/doc/dnsmasq-base/examples/dnsmasq.conf.example
```

This is probably due to my use of Network Manager.

I plan to use `dhcpd-hpa` to serve the PXE stuff. Are there landmines?

Comment: Install dnsmasq package
rpm -q dnsmasq;
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq

Comment: @JackyChan `dnsmasq` is already installed as part of the `dnsmasq-base` package. It just seems to be configured strangely due to NetworkManager,

Comment: ok, copy dnsmasq.conf file from hope this should be help-
cp /usr/share/doc/dnsmasq-base/examples/dnsmasq.conf.example /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Comment: Comment moved to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JackyChan After the `cp /usr/share/doc/dnsmasq-base/examples/dnsmasq.conf.example /etc/dnsmasq.conf`, I did

```
inotifywatch -t 180 -v --event access /etc/dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.d/ /etc/dnsmasq.d-available/
```

while, in another window, did

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

`inotifywatch` detected no accesses.

After further research, I put the file (all #comments and blank lines, for now) in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf`, and ran

```
inotifywatch -t 180 -v --event access /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf
```

while, in another window, did I

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

`inotifywatch` saw 7 accesses to `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf`

The directory `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` is where `dnsmasq.conf` is sought, for a `NetworkManager` controlled `dnsmasq`