# Changing /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: networking, network-manager

In Ubuntu 18.04 the workings of `/etc/resolv.conf` changed again. Tools break as a result. For example OpenShift local cluster depends on this file.

On the internet it is possible to find how this file can be changed under Ubuntu 12.02 relatively easy.

Is there any documentation that describes how this file works and how its contents can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Under NetworkManager, the file to change is `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf`. For my reasoning, see my answer at [Ubuntu 16.04 Network Manager DHCP and PXE setup. Can't find `dnsmasq.conf`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093495/ubuntu-16-04-network-manager-dhcp-and-pxe-setup-cant-find-dnsmasq-conf)

Read `man dnsmasq;man 5 resolver`.